# Thumbnails of posted Images are cropped but not scaled in Slack

Tags: slack

When posting an image the thumbnail version displayed in Slack is a cropped not scaled version. For example, look at this this image

> [image]

When posted in Slack, the thumbnail image displayed in Slack channel is this:

> [image]

Now if one *clicks* on that image the original/full version is displayed. But that's inconvenient.

Is there any configuration to get Slack to be less lazy about what it displays for images in the channel?